# Compile Error: Loop must iterate over a collection type: Map<Id,List<Event>>

Tags: apex, loop, compile-error, collection

In the code below, I get an error on the bolded line. Says Loop must iterate over a collection type: Map>

Any idea how to troubleshoot?

```
Map<Id, List<Event>> events = new Map<Id, List<Event>>();
for (Event record : [
    SELECT WhoId FROM Event
    WHERE WhoId IN :contactIds
    AND WhatId = null
    AND Type = 'MQL'
]){
    if (!events.containsKey(record.WhoId))
        events.put(record.WhoId, new List<Event>());
    events.get(event.WhoId).add(event);
}

for (Opportunity record : trigger.new)
{
    if (!ocrs.containsKey(record.Id)) continue;
    for (OpportunityContactRole ocr : ocrs.get(record.Id))
    {
        if (!events.containsKey(ocr.ContactId)) continue;
        for (Event event : events.get(ocr.ContactId))
            event.WhatId = record.Id;
    }
}
List<Event> eventsToUpdate = new List<Event>();
**for (List<Event> contactSpecificEvents : events)**
{
    eventsToUpdate.addAll(contactSpecificEvents);
}
update eventsToUpdate;
}
```

Comment: put bit details about what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Loop variable needs to be `events.values()`.

Comment: @brooksbruce can you please check my ans and close this question

Comment: Sorry. For some reason it wouldn't let me check your answer yesterday. There was a time limit I had to wait for. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you have declared `Map<Id, List<Event>> events = new Map<Id, List<Event>>();`

So, to loop through the `List` of events you need to use `events.values()`

```
for (List<Event> contactSpecificEvents : events.values())
{
    eventsToUpdate.addAll(contactSpecificEvents);
}
```